# Law of brownian bridge

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

I am having some trouble prooving the following result:
[image]

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Start by finding the joint distribution of $(W(\bar{t}),W(t),W(\underline{t}))$, then find the conditional distribution.

Comment: I found my answer here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412470/conditional-distribution-in-brownian-motion Thanks everyone